# Ignore FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK on android.intent.action.SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to have other apps share PDF files with mine, I have an intent filter for android.intent.action.SEND type pdf files but some apps send the intent with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK which closes the activity that was already running.

Is there any way to ignore this flag? I want to keep the current activity running when shared to my app.

EDIT: a good example

- I share a PDF with google drive pdf viewer, my activity that is already running picks it up and the intent is received in "onNewIntent" (desired).
- When I do the same thing with Samsungs "my files" my activity gets restarted and the intent is given to "onCreate" (not desired)

Comment: "Is there any way to ignore this flag?" -- not that I am aware of. "I want to keep the current activity running when shared to my app" -- what is the specific reason why you want this? The activity may be gone for other reasons, such as Android terminating your process while your app is in the background.

Comment: @CommonsWare It's a flutter app - which means the whole app is ran in one acttivity. I need to receive the sharing intent in the running activity to catch it.

Comment: "I need to receive the sharing intent in the running activity to catch it." - I'm not sure what you're getting at. The flag will clear the task your activity is to be launched in. THEN your activity will be started. You will receive the intent in YOUR running activity. The state of the other activities should be irrelevant to you.

Comment: @dominicoder My activity gets restarted when sharing to my app depending on which other app is sharing a PDF to my app.

Example: I share a PDF with google drive pdf viewer, my activity that is already running picks it up and the intent is received in "onNewIntent" (desired). When I do the same thing with Samsungs "my files" my activity gets restarted and the intent is given to "onCreate"

Answer (score 0):

> I share a PDF with google drive pdf viewer, my activity that is already running picks it up and the intent is received in "onNewIntent" (desired).

> When I do the same thing with Samsungs "my files" my activity gets restarted and the intent is given to "onCreate" (not desired)

Your app should work correctly regardless of how it's invoked. What difference does it make to you whether it's a new instance receiving the intent or the existing one? You're not always going to have an existing instance around, right? If you share from Google before starting your activity, you'll be in the same position, won't you?

Comment: That doesn't matter. When there is no existing activity it habdles it right as well - it's bad for _adding_ files to the existing activity. If the app restarts you have to relogin and the view list is empty again. If the intention was to add a file, the list is clear which is undesired. (Note that i cannot change the relogin behaviour, thats a policy from the client)

Comment: I don't understand your use case from your comment. Perhaps if you clarify what you're ultimately trying to achieve, or what your app does, or what it's current structure is, it'll be easier to give you suggestions on how to solve the problem.